# Android Sqlite taking more time on query execution for first time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using sqlite in my android application, I am having a huge size database in my application. I have a single table with 300K entries with indexed column.

**Query** :  `SELECT SOME_COLUMN FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 'some_text' ORDER BY SOME_COLUMN DESC`

When the above query is hit for the first time since the app being installed in mobile it took around **7- 9 Sec**

After every consecutive call to the db gives me around **200 - 250 mills sec**.
Even I tried restarting the app it would gives me the same **200 - 250 mills sec**.

Why does there is a huge difference, any caching mechanism used inside it, if so how long the caching would work ?
Can anyone explain about this.

Comment: `Once opened successfully, the database is cached` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/db/SupportSQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it states only the db instance is cached, not the query execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization you can try is to create an [index](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/) for the columns you are querying.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_list);
```

If it happens the first time after install, it may be caused by system loading the app's cache for the first time.